# How can I jump to the next cell in a table?

Tags: javascript

I have a table wherein the first column is a checkbox and the second one has a text.
Whenever, the checkbox is checked, I want to know the corresponding value which is in the next cell. 
Please tell me how to do.
If I use the getelementsbytagname function, it returns from the start of the document.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple to do without jquery. We have a input inside a `td` so we can go up a level and get the next sibling:

```
var nextTd = myInput.parentNode.nextSibling;
```

Because some browser insert empty text nodes between `td`s we can do the following to make sure we're on the right node:

```
if (nextTd.tagName != "TD")
    nextTd = nextTd.nextSibling;
```

---

Also, FWIW, `getElementsByTagName` can be called from any Node. Thus, if I have a table, I can call

```
myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

To return all rows inside of `myTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery (or some other civilized framework), it's pretty easy:

```
$('table#yourTableId input:checkbox').click(function(ev) {
  if (this.checked) {
    // not sure what you mean by "want to know" ...
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
  }
});
```

You could do it with the jQuery "live" event facility similarly, which'd be cheaper if there are a lot of checkboxes.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be yo use jQuery or a similar library, that implements CSS3 selectors.

```
$('table input:checked').parent().parent().find('td.nth-child(2)').text():
```

You could also bind onto the change events of the checkboxes

```
$('input:checkbox').change = function(){
    val = $(this).parent().parent().find('td.nth-child(2)').text():
}
```